# manage.py and other.py files is not in same level file

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I have Django 1.4 and Python 2.6.6
When I use "django-amdin.py startproject djproject" follow the steps in webpage
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/linux/l-django/#resources
And I get files as follows:

```
djproject/
|-- djproject
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- wsgi.py
`-- manage.py
```

Note: manage.py and other.py files is not in same level folder, Why?

++++++

```
DATABASES = {  
    'default': {  
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.  
        'NAME': 'db/tdata.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.  
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.  
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.  
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.  
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.  
    }  
}
```

When I configure 'ENGINE' as 'sqlite3' instead of 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', I got the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sqlite3' isn't an available database backend.  
Try using django.db.backends.sqlite3 instead.  
Error was: No module named base
```

Is that also a new character of 1.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was changed [in Django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py):

> Django 1.4 ships with an updated default project layout and manage.py
>   file for the startproject management command. These fix some issues
>   with the previous manage.py handling of Python import paths that
>   caused double imports, trouble moving from development to deployment,
>   and other difficult-to-debug path issues.

Answer (score 1):

Project directory structure changed in Django 1.4

More detailes here - http://www.tdd-django-tutorial.com/blog/articles/2012/tutorials-updated-django-14-and-its-weird-new-fold/